# Assign type to column

Tags: matlab

I've imported the data of daily returns into a MatLab matrix using the importdata function: 
19990104    0.0269360000000000
19990105    0.0170490000000000
...

I need to create a histogram of data in the second column. What's the best way to create a histogram of data in the second column? Do I need to assign types to columns separately?

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: please provide an input example (a few rows will do)

Comment: you can use hist(data(:,2))

Comment: this worked, thank you!!